# Jena and jsp mismatch type

Tags: jsp, servlets, path, rdf

friends. Well it is a long question, but according Jack, let's go by parts.
In this snippet
++++++++++

```
<% 
List<`enter code here`String> sugestao =  request.getAttribute("sugestao");
Iterator it = sugestao.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    out.print("<br> conceito:"+ it.next());
}
%>
```

I got an error message saying that there is a type mismatch, so that it is not possible to convert an object to a List. "sugestao" came from a servlet.
{...}

```
List<String> sugestao = listaConceitos.getListaConceitos(caminho);
request.setAttribute("sugestao", sugestao);
RequestDispatcher view = request
    .getRequestDispatcher("SequenciaDosConceitos.jsp");
// passa para frente.
view.forward(request, response);}}
```

BTW: caminho is a RDF path.
I need some help to solve this trouble. I tryied a type cast, but didn't work... I need some hint? I got lost in the sea of Java!

Answer (score 2):

The `ServletRequest.getAttribute()` method does not support generics. Change the line

```
List<String> sugestao =  request.getAttribute("sugestao");
```

to

```
List<String> sugestao =  (List<String>) request.getAttribute("sugestao");
```

Obviously, this will only work if `sugestao` is of type `List<String>`. So somewhere in your code you should have something like this:

```
List<String> sugestao = new ArrayList<String>();
// do stuff...
request.setAttribute("sugestao", sugestao);
```

Comment: Thank you, home. Some troubles still remain. One weird thing: as I run, for the first time, everything is all right, but if I try for the second time, I get an exception. If I go to Eclipse Project tab, and check clean...it runs all right again. Why? There also some warnings at jsp page, I had to use @suppressWarnings...it is not a nice solution, but as I am using scriptlets ...

Comment: Which exception do you get? Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: Ok, it is solved. I went to Project Tab and checked "Build Automatically", it seems that this module is ok, now. Thank you for your suggestions. It helped me to do a great leap forward...